# Am I damaging my induction cooker by putting piece of metal under aluminium pan?

Tags: heat, inductance

[Moved from SE Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342884/am-i-damaging-my-induction-cooker-by-putting-peace-of-metal-under-aluminium-pan)

I have bought induction cooker and to use my old cooking pan I have placed a sheet of metal and it seems to work ok...

[However it is making hissing noise](https://youtu.be/h6tw_inxsS4)... am I damaging my induction cooker by doing this...

**Am I damaging my induction cooker by putting piece of metal under aluminum pan?**

P.S I already got a proper metal pan this question is just for educational purposes

Comment: What metal do you put under the aluminium pan?

Comment: @peufeu some rusty iron(assumption) sheet  I have found near the road

Comment: Iron is OK, induction cookers are designed for ferromagnetic pans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Your induction stove don't care what it's heating as long as the resonant frequency and impedance stay within specification and unless the manufacturer really screwed up, it's protected against it. Case in point, does it detect when a pot is removed and start beeping? That's the protection kicking in.

Hissing noise is unfortunately normal for induction stoves.